# "Apply Style" window is lost in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, view, window

In visual studio 2010 Ultimate I was working with Apply Style window and I temporarily closed this window by clicking X on it. Later when I look for it under View > Apply Style (its usual place) it wasn't there. devenv /resetsettings not seem to be working for me. any idea on how I can return the window back?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by resetting the settings..
From Menu, *Tools* > *Import and Export Settings* is selected and using the wizard IDE is reset. Then the lost icons come back (visible and ready) under *View*.

Answer (score 1):

Try Tools-->Customize and then look for the Add Command button, where you can find the Apply Styles window under the "View" category.

Comment: The icon comes back but it is not possible to click it (the icon is gray). I also realized that "manage style" icon is lost, too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to switch to HTML (Web Form) Explorer.

in your solution explorer

right click on index.html > 
    Open with... > 
        HTML (Web Form) Explorer

then in your visual studio toolbar select VIEW and you should find Apply Style now

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?